# MYSQL select count(*) in one table if id exists in another table

Tags: mysql, sql, select, count, where-clause

This should be really simple but I'm stuck on it and couldn't find the answer here.

I want to count the number of records in one table that match a given `user_id` if that `user_id` exists in another table, or if not return -1.

Something like:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM table_1
WHERE user_id = (IF EXISTS table_2.user_id = '22')
, ELSE -1;
```

In summary, if `table_2` contains a `user_id` of 22, then return the number of records in `table_1` with a `user_id` of 22, or if not, return -1.

How do I do this please? (NB. Just to clarify, `user_id` is not a primary key in either table)

**EDIT:** adding table sample:

```
table_1
---------------------
user_id  |  item
---------------------
22       |  apple
23       |  orange
22       |  banana

table_2
---------------------
user_id  |  name
---------------------
20       |  billy
21       |  bob
22       |  thornton
```

So running the query I need with `user_id = 21` would return `0`, running with `user_id = 22` would return `2` and with `user_id = 23` would return `-1`.

Comment: Can you provide sample data and desired results?  Your request doesn't make sense to me.  You have a comparison in the `where` and then you are saying that something returns `-1`.

Answer (score 1):

One neat (dirty?) trick you can use is to select counts from both tables and cross join the results. Since you're querying aggregate functions with no `group by` clauses, you're guaranteed to get one row in each result:

```
SELECT     CASE cnt_2 WHEN 0 THEN -1 ELSE cnt_1 END 
FROM       (SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt_1
            FROM   table_1
            WHERE  user_id = 22) t
CROSS JOIN (SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt_2
            FROM   table_2
            WHERE  user_id = 22) s
```

Comment: JOIN is a penalty.

Comment: This looks a little overly complicated and perhaps expensive doing two counts and a join? I don't need to count the number of matches in table_2, just need to know if there is at least one match.

Comment: MySql returns error:  #1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias

Comment: @freeworlder oops, forgot about that limitation in MySQL. Edited and fixed.

Comment: It works! Great! Is this really the most efficient way do you think?

Answer (score 1):

Does this give you the result you need?

```
SELECT
CASE COUNT(*) WHEN 0 THEN -1 ELSE COUNT(*) END AS row_count
FROM table_1
WHERE user_id = 22
AND (
  SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM table_2
  WHERE user_id = 22) >= 1;
```

It uses a CASE statement to implement the check and show -1 if no records are found. It uses a subquery in the WHERE clause to find the count of records in table_2, and checks that it is greater than or equal to 1.

There are a couple of ways to do this - it could possibly be done with a LEFT JOIN or an EXISTS, but I think this will work.

Comment: I couldn't get this to work. Lots of syntax errors.Unexpected keyword. (near "COUNT" at position 12)
Unexpected end of CASE expression (near " " at position 11)
Unrecognized keyword. (near "COUNT" at position 12)
Unexpected token. (near "(" at position 17)
Unexpected token. (near "*" at position 18)
Unexpected token. (near ")" at position 19)
Unrecognized keyword. (near "WHEN" at position 21)
Unexpected token. (near "0" at position 26)
Unrecognized keyword. (near "THEN" at position 28)
Unexpected token. (near "-1" at position 33)... ??

Comment: I'm not sure why those syntax errors are appearing, using SELECT COUNT(*) and CASE is valid syntax. I'll check it against a MySQL database when I get the chance.

Comment: I checked the syntax and it looks fine. Do you have any extra quotes or did you make any changes to this?